# Error with data store in vector in C++

Tags: c++

I try to make a list of digit of consequence number from 1 to 100; for example, 123456789101112..... However, when I print out the result from the list_result; there is some strange number in my list_result vector. Here the following code:

```
int main()
{
vector<int> list_num;
vector<int> list_result;
int count =0;
for(int index = 1; index<=100; index++)
{
    count = index;
    if(index<10)
    {
        list_result.push_back(index);
    }
    else
    {
        while(count!=0)
        {
            list_num.push_back(count%10);
            count=count/10;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<=list_num.size();i++)
        {
            list_result.push_back(list_num[list_num.size()-i]);
        }
        list_num.clear();
    }

for(int i = 0; i<=list_result.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<list_result[i];
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Anyone has any ideas? Thank,

Comment: What's the strange output you're seeing? Can you include it in the question?

Comment: Compile with all warnings (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

```
    for(int i=0; i<=list_num.size();i++)
    {
        list_result.push_back(list_num[list_num.size()-i]);
    }
```

Valid indexes into `list_num` are 0 through `list_num.size()-1`. Yet on the first iteration of this loop, when `i == 0`, you attempt to access `list_num[list_num.size()]`. There is no such element.

Answer (score 0):

Igor Tandetnik described an issue in the `for` loop inside the `else` block, but I've identified another issue, this time in the output stage of the program.

Remember that indices are zero-based, which means they run from zero to the number of elements *minus one*. `vector::size()` returns the total number of elements, in this case 100. Because you're comparing this value with the index using a less-than-or-equal inequality, you end up trying to access element 100 on the final iteration of the loop, and element 100 does not exist since the range of valid indices is 0 to 99. When writing a loop that iterates through an array or vector, you should always compare indices with array/vector sizes using *strict inequalities*.

In the final `for` loop, replace the `<=` with a strict `<` comparison so that it stops at the actual last element and not afterwards:

```
for(int i = 0; i<list_result.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<list_result[i];
}
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) has an easy-to-understand explanation of this common programming mistake, known as an *off-by-one error*.